# Data sorting from Excel sheet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i tried to sort the values of particular row in data frame, the values are sorting but index values are not changing....i want to change the index values also according to the sorted data

```
rld=pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\DELL\nagrajun sagar reservoir data - Copy.xlsx")
rl = rld.iloc[:,1].sort_values()
rl
```

output:

```
15    0.043
3     0.370
17    0.391
2     0.823
16    1.105
1     1.579
0     2.070
12    2.235
4     2.728
18    4.490
9     4.905
13    5.036
14    5.074
11    6.481
10    6.613
6     6.806
7     6.807
8     6.824
5     6.841
Name:  2  October, dtype: float64
rl[0]
output:
2.07
```

I expected `rl[0]` as 0.043 but actual result is 2.07 which is index value of before sorted list...

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you can try [`reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `(drop=True)`

Something like `rl=rl.reset_index(drop=True)` in your case or you can do it while sorting like:

```
rl = rld.iloc[:,1].sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)
```